# Need to display the content

Tags: xslt

This is my input html-body

```
 <body class="calibre">
   Gabriel García Márquez 
   <p class="calibre1">Prêmio Nobel de Literatura </p>
   <p class="calibre1"></p>
 </body>
```

I am using xslt1.0.

```
<xsl:message>value=<xsl:copy-of 
                        select="xhtml:html/xhtml:body/*"/></xsl:message>
```

produces output a empty. How to get the nodes and also the text..
Please help me..Thanks in advance

Comment: Besides namespace issue, your stylesheet fragment isn't significant...

Answer (score 1):

Your input has no namespace. Remove the namespace in your stylesheet.

Comment: But in some input i am having namespaces like <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">..Thats why i used namespaces..Any common method to satisfy both this.

Comment: <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <body class="calibre">
<h1 class="calibre2" id="calibre_pb_0">     </h1><p class="calibre1">
  </p><p class="calibre1">
 </p><p class="calibre1">
Cem anos de solidão </p><p class="calibre1">
 </p><p class="calibre1">
Tradução de ELIANE ZAGURY </p><p class="calibre1">
   </p></body>
</html>

Comment: @Vignesh, ok, there's a namespace in your HTML, but it isn't `xhtml`, it's `w3.org/1999/xhtml`. You haven't shown your full stylesheet, are you correctly declaring `xhtml` as a namespace prefix?